# Getting JSON keys/values, and updating SQL table at columns (key1, key2, ...) with values (val1, val2, ...)

Tags: php, sql, ajax, pdo

I am sending a JSON array with this data to my server:

```
[{"name":"Dinner","value":"3"},
{"name":"Happy_Hour","value":"3"},
{"name":"client_id","value":"55"}]
```

using AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: 'http://****',
    data: MyJsonArray,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: 'submitCallback',
    success: function(){
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown){
        alert("submit interests error" + status);
    },
    complete: function(){
    }
}); //ajax
```

I would then like to update a table for the column names ("Dinner" and "Happy_Hour") with the values for each respective name using PHP. Normally, I would use `$_GET['Happy_Hour']`, and `UPDATE table_name SET Happy_Hour=?, etc_etc=? WHERE id=?`, but now I should somehow iterate through an array in order get the keys/value.  How can I transition from having to use `$_GET['hardcoded_name']` to getting an array of those keys/values?

**EDIT**

The JSON object I referred to was actually an array, so I changed it (top). I got it by calling `MyHTMLForm.serializeArray();`

Comment: For the record `$GET_['hardcoded_name']` should be `$_GET['hardcoded_name']` - typo.

Comment: $contents = file_get_contents(php://input);

Comment: Is it a JSON array, or a JSON object? You say it is both. Also the data you show in the question isn't valid JSON.

Comment: Why would you set `async` to `false`? You're going to hang your application if anything goes wrong.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling The PHP is protected.

Comment: @Frumples ok -- just checking ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want use a hardcoded indices you can put it inside to another parent:

```
$.ajax({
   data: {data: MyJsonObject},
   // ... others
});
```

Then on the PHP script, call that parent holder:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['data'])) {
    $data = $_GET['data'];
    foreach($data as $val) {
        $val['name'] // the particular key Dinner, ,Happy_Hour
        $val['value'] // the corresponding value 3, 3, 55
        // rest of insert code
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Are you thinking that I will have to execute an UPDATE for each name/value pair?

Comment: @Frumples no, since you want a dynamic indices, gather each key pair, and line them up, thats your question right? instead of explicitly putting the index name, get a dynamic key pair instead. by the way did you even try this? or do i have to answer also how to line them up?

Comment: @Frumples by they way, if you're going to insert them thru prepared statements. you cant bind those columns so you need to just whitelist them, anyway its getting out of the topic

Comment: You just answered the full extent of my question in your last (aggressive) comments.  Thank you.

Comment: @Frumples actually i already wrote an answer like this before with regards to having dynamic inputs inside a prepared statement using reflection class, i just cant find it anywhere, regarding with the columns, thats just my take, since you can't bind them, you can just whitelist, gather the table columns and compare.